# How to setup CICFlowmeter in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, security, wireshark, packet-sniffers, packet-capture

I am trying to use CICFlowmeter (https://pypi.org/project/cicflowmeter/) which is a tool that extracts feature from pcap file and converts them into a csv file. I have tried on windows 10,11 but for that we need Tcpdump which is incompatible with windows. If someone could help with setting up on Ubuntu I would really appreciate it.

Tried Windows 10,11. Tried on Ubuntu but as I am new to it, I feel I am having issues with directories. I have installed CICFlowmeter from the link ( from python) but unable to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution:

I was unable to set it up on linux however, the tool works fine with Windows 10, 11. It can be downloaded from the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folder...

Once downloaded, extract it, go to bin and open the batch file and you will see GUI asking you to perform offline or real time analysis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).